# Which metric measures the distance of two nodes in a graph, also accounting for the number of alternative routes

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to measure the "closeness" of two nodes $i$ and $j$ on an undirected, unweighed graph. The ideal metric I'd be interested in has the flowing properties:

1. Strictly increasing in the number of paths from $i$ to $j$
2. Decreasing in the length of each path from $i$ to $j$

I was thinking of using the sum of the inverse of path-lengths from $i$ to $j$. This would have the desired properties. I am quite sure thought that this must already have a name. I failed at googleing it though.

**Some background**:
I'm trying to measure social proximity in a social network. The idea is that (i) the shorter the chain between two people and (ii) the more common friends there are, the more socially proximate they are.

Answer (score 1):

Only a start an an answer, too long for a comment.

You're asking a well studied question. If you google

> https://www.google.com/#q=measuring+proximity+in+graphs

you'll find ideas for lots of algorithms that address your problem.

I suggest you start here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~wcohen/10-802/fixed/Different_proximity_measurements_on_graphs.html